# Is it possible to access static resource of a managed package in a local VF page

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, static-resources

Is it possible to access a static resource of a managed package in your local environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is possible; the name needs qualifying using the managed package namespace prefix. So if that namespace prefix is "abc", this will work:

```
<apex:image value="{!$Resource.abc__LogoImage}"/>
```

But bear in mind that while the author of the managed package can't remove that static resource in future versions therefore guaranteeing that your page/code will always compile, there is the possibility that they will change the content and so leave you with unexpected results in your page/code. For that reason you are normally safer maintaining your own copy of the static resource.